# Arrange a table on a page in two columns

Tags: tables

In an article with two columns, I would like to display a table that greatly exceeds the page margin with numbers.

Is there a way to display the table correctly on the column, in two levels perhaps?

```latex
\begin{tabular}{llccccccc}
\toprule
type & count &         mean &           std &    min &     25\% &     50\% &      75\% &      max \\
\midrule
square &   447 &   457.800895 &    650.332632 &   30.0 &   181.5 &   310.0 &    496.5 &   9352.0 \\
circle     &   149 &  7853.624161 &  11287.188363 &  228.0 &  1717.0 &  4149.0 &  10164.0 &  73344.0 \\
triangle &   220 &   328.522727 &    325.778820 &   42.0 &   160.0 &   254.5 &    370.0 &   3659.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: it's very hard to help if you only provide a fragment without giving any indication of the column widths (or the definition of the non standard commands, although I may guess that).   You coudl use a smaller font such as `\small` or `\footnotesize`  and use `@{}` to remve the padding at teh left and right of the table or ....

Comment: the question is essentially a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you very much for the link. The width of the columns must be wide enough to accommodate a six digit number. Yes I tried but I don't understand very well where to place the \small and the @{}.. could you just give me an example?

Comment: `\small\begin{tabular}{@{}llccccccc@{}}` but as you have not provided a test example, it isn't possible to say if that is enough tomake it fit.

Comment: It's not enought.. I edited with a test example.

Comment: This really is just a duplicate of the standard "table too wide" question, any of the answers there apply. You can use \footnotesize (or even \tiny) if you must  or re-arrange your data in a different format (eg swap rows and columns) or make it a spanning table that is full page width.  The example code posted is no help to anyone unless it starts \documentclass and ends \end{document}  without knowing how wide your columns are and what size your font is, impossible to give any definite answer just general hints.

Comment: If you want a more specific advice on how you can make sure this particular table fits into the available space, please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce your output. Alos, your code does not match the screenshot of the table. (horizontal lines and alignment in the column differ)

Comment: Put the  `tabular` into a `table*`  to fill the two columns on next page (if possible).